# Came back to my computer to find that one screen was normal and the other had lines through it

Tags: windows

I came back to my PC today after leaving it a good few hours. I locked the PC, turned off the screens and then came back, turned on the screens and one was my normal lock screen colour and the other was completely grey with black lines through it... :(

3 Days ago, I got my PC's manufacturer to change my CPU, same Haswell and all of that, and I asked the forums if I needed to reinstall windows, everyone said it wasn't needed, even the people who changed my CPU.

I also have the new AMD Crimson Driver, which seems to be fine.

I'm running Windows 8.1, what do you guys thing happened? There are no errors in the System tab in the event log, and no errors in the reliability history except from when I had to force it shut down... Did the temperatures somehow rise?

Found the error but it was somehow reported after?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is needed! You have to reinstall Windows after changing CPU... it's not Linux. It only installs core drivers once, during installation.

Comment: Really? You're the first person to say this.

Comment: That's what I know from my own experiences :) Changing CPU or Motherboard makes Windows go crazy, blue screens or black screens, eventually crashes. In most cases it won't even run.

Comment: @Sammyjo20 If the processor is the same architecture and has at least the same features and instruction sets as the old, you shouldn't have to reinstall Windows. (You might get licensing problems if you change too much stuff at once, though.)